I am trying to build a server that enables me to ceate a product and connect this to my frontend. But it i am not receiving the response
So, I am trying to work on the products page in my management software. What i want is when the user lands on the product page, they are able to see their products then also add products. But my requests are not going through and i am not able to make post request that creates the products. Let me share my code with you.
App.jsx
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import Layout from './components/shared/Layout';
import Products from './components/Products';
import ProductForm from './components/ProductForm';


function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
       <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
            <Route path="/add-product" element={<ProductForm />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="login" element={<div>This is the login page</div>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Then I also have my ProductForm.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function ProductForm({ setProducts }) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    description: '',
    category: '',
    sku: '',
    barcode: '',
    quantityInStock: '',
    unitPrice: '',
    costPrice: '',
    reorderLevel: '',
    supplierId: '',
    warehouseLocation: '',
    status: '',
    imageUrl: '',
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/add-product', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to add product');
      }
      navigate('/products');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding product:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div className='bg-white px-4 py-6 rounded-sm border border-gray-200 w-full mb-8'>
      <h2 className='text-xl mb-4 font-bold'>Add Product</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-6">
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Name</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='name'
            value={formData.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Description</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='description'
            value={formData.description}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1  focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Category</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='category'
            value={formData.category}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>SKU</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='sku'
            value={formData.sku}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1  focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Barcode</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='barcode'
            value={formData.barcode}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Quantity in Stock</label>
          <input
            type='number'
            name='quantityInStock'
            value={formData.quantityInStock}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Unit Price</label>
          <input
            type='number'
            name='unitPrice'
            value={formData.unitPrice}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Cost Price</label>
          <input
            type='number'
            name='costPrice'
            value={formData.costPrice}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Reorder Level</label>
          <input
            type='number'
            name='reorderLevel'
            value={formData.reorderLevel}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Supplier ID</label>
          <input
            type='number'
            name='supplierId'
            value={formData.supplierId}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Warehouse Location</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='warehouseLocation'
            value={formData.warehouseLocation}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Status</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='status'
            value={formData.status}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label className='block text-gray-700'>Image URL</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='imageUrl'
            value={formData.imageUrl}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className='border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mt-1 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none'
          />
        </div>
        <div className='col-span-3'>
            <button type='submit' className='bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md col-span-1 mt-4'>
            Submit
            </button>
       
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

and server.jsx
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
// Endpoint to create a new product
app.post('/add-product', async (req, res) => {
  const {
    name, description, category, sku, barcode,
    quantityInStock, unitPrice, costPrice, reorderLevel,
    supplierId, warehouseLocation, status, imageUrl
  } = req.body;

  try {
    const newProduct = await prisma.product.create({
      data: {
        name, description, category, sku, barcode,
        quantityInStock, unitPrice, costPrice, reorderLevel,
        supplierId, warehouseLocation, status, imageUrl
      },
    });
    res.json({data: newProduct});
    console.log('Product created:', newProduct);
    res.status(201).json({ data: newProduct }); // Return the created product data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating product:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error creating product' });
  }
});

// Endpoint to fetch all products
app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await prisma.product.findMany();
    res.json(products);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error fetching products' });
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

please some quick help here

What debugging have you done? It's much easier for you to do than us because you can logs results in the console both for browser and node, you can use the debugger in the browser to step through the code and see where the problems are.

@Andy...Actually am quite new to react, node and express...I have been trying to see how to best do this, because there is totally nothing in my console when i submit the form. I used dev tools and it tells me that the route "localhost:3000/add-product" does not exist. I get the 404 not found error code.

Hi, Kindly check or share the output of the statement : console.error('Error adding product:', error);

I noticed I was running both frontend and backend on the same port. So I changed the frontend and ran it on a different port. Then I had to add proxy settings in my package.json. Everything is running just fine.
